# Having Trouble Importing JSON file into Python Dictionary format

Tags: python, json

I am having issues importing a json file (downloaded from USPTO website) - here is how the data looks:

[Image of JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TogBf.png)

The code I attempted to use is:

```
   import json
   with open('2020.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
```

I receive an error "Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 20 with the image shown.

I have tried changing the ',' at that position to ':' and the data seems to load fine into the "data" variable as a dictionary.  However, when I run print(len(data)), it returns '1'.

The number of entries is obviously not '1'.  I am hoping to be able to eventually convert the data into a dataframe for further data manipulation.  Any suggestions on how to correct this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: validate your JSON here https://jsonformatter.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think the file may have some weird characters that are only readable in binary format. This worked for me in Python 3.7 on Windows:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('2020.json', 'rb') as f:
...     data = json.loads(f.read())
...
>>> type(data)
<class 'dict'>
>>> len(data.keys())
1
>>> list(data.keys())
['PatentBulkData']
>>>
```

Without doing 'rb' as the format, i was getting something odd (though not the same as what you saw:

```
>>> f = open('2020.json', 'r')
>>> json.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 11411895: character maps to <undefined>
```

Also in the future it may be useful to include the location the json file came from (if its publicly downloadable). (I believe) I found it from here https://ped.uspto.gov/peds/.